# How can I fix the product boxes on my website?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, responsive

I have a question regarding an image box from Woocommerce. I already tried several things but it looks like a bug. On desktop the products boxes are nice, but on tablet or mobile, the left ones becama a lot smaller. The website is: https://meerdaneenlintje.nl/product-categorie/lintjes/ .

If anyone has an solution I am glad to hear that!

Kind regards,

Joppe

Comment: This problem is related to the theme CSS. You can edit it and fix the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the margin added to the first and second columns. The last column element does not have a left margin.

```css
@media (min-width: 545px) and (max-width: 921px)
.woocommerce[class*="columns-"] ul.products li.product:nth-child(n), .woocommerce-page[class*="columns-"] ul.products li.product:nth-child(n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
    clear: none;
}
```

[image: with margin-right: 20px;]

---

**Removing the margin for the first columns fixes the problem** :

[image: without margin-right: 20px;]